# Form validation returns reference error

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've made a form and a calculator that are supposed to place a simple order on a website. I'm trying to make it so that if the value is less than 1 you get an error on submitting, but for some reason this wont work.

I think it has something to do with <1 but i'm not sure.

This is my code:

```
if  (ATotal == <1){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "Please specify an amount.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well if you want less than one then you just write `ATotal < 1` not `ATotal == <1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, ***== <1*** is wrong. Maybe you want

```
ATotal == 1
```

or

```
ATotal <= 1
```